# how can i do a unit testing of axios.create mock with vitest?

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3, vitest, axios-mock-adapter

i am learning unit testing in vue with typescript and i want to test this function

```
const getCLients =async (): Promise<Client[]> => {
        const {data} = await clientsApi.get('/clients')
        return data
}
```

But i got an error due to the clientsApi. My clients api is aun axios instance and looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const clientsApi = axios.create({
   baseURL:import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
})
export default clientsApi
```

my error is this:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
> ❯ getCLients ../src/clients/composables/useClients.ts:14:41

> 14|         const {data} = await clientsApi.get('/clients')

In my tests i have done the axios mock:

```
vi.mock('axios')
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
            data: mockClients,
})
```

I suposed that i had to make a mock of the axios.create but i have tried with a lot of ways but i always got the same typoe error. I need your help, how could you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm on the right track as it just works on my end. I do `vi.mock('axios')` and have `Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy uponenter code here`. So I do `vi.mock(the path to the instance )`, and do `vi.spyOn(the axios instance, 'get').mockResolvedValue` and in your case, could be `clientsApi`.

Answer (score 0):

If, for instance, you're using `axios.create()` in your codebase to generate an `AxiosInstance`, you can mock this functionality as follows in your Vitest test file:

```js
const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({
  get: vi.fn(),
  post: vi.fn(),
  // and any other request type you want to mock
}));

vi.mock('axios', async(importActual) => {
  const actual = await importActual<typeof import ('axios')>();

  const mockAxios = {
    default: {
      ...actual.default,
      create: vi.fn(() => ({
        ...actual.default.create(),
        get: mocks.get,
        post: mocks.post,
      })),
    },
  };

  return mockAxios;
});
```

Initially, we set up the `mocks` object that includes the `get` and `post` functions we want to mock. Using `vi.hoisted()`, we ensure these mocked functions are hoisted (i.e., moved to the top of the scope), allowing us to reference them within our `vi.mock()` function.

Then, we mock the entire `axios` module using `vi.mock()`. In order to maintain the existing functionality that we don't intend to mock, we employ `importActual` to import the real `axios` module. We then specify the parts we wish to mock, namely the `create` function and the `get`/`post` functions.

With these mocks in place, we can now spy on our mocked `get` and `post` methods. Here's an example of how to do it:

```js
it('should call axios.get', async() => {
  mocks.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: {},
  });
  await clientsApi.getCLients();
  expect(mocks.get).toHaveBeenCalled(); // should return true
});
```

In the test case, we mock a resolved value for our `get` method and call the function we want to test (`clientsApi.getCLients()` in this case). We then check whether our mocked `get` function has been called using `expect().toHaveBeenCalled()`.

This setup provides a controlled environment to test the interactions with the axios library in our code.

Comment: Please do not post [the same answer to more than one question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76606869/471272). Also, do not post ChatGPT answers, because they are plagiarism violating the Code of Conduct and officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: I came up with this solution on my own. I only used ChatGPT to reword my explanation; however, I didn't know that would be a problem because I just wanted to improve the clarity of my answer. Additionally, I tweaked this answer in the second question, they were the same question but my answer is different in the code snippets.