# Mocking axios.create using vitest

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, vitest

I am using `axios.create` method to create and configure `axios` instance. And I can't get it to work in tests with `vi.fn()` so I cannot assert if endpoint was called.

workaround for tests to be able to return data from api calls looks like

```
  return {
    AxiosInstance: {},
    AxiosRequestConfig: {},
    default: {
      post: vi.fn(),
      create: vi.fn(() => {
        return {
          post: (url: string, config: object) => {
            return Promise.resolve({ status: 200 });
          },
          get: (url: string, config: object) => {
            return Promise.resolve({ status: 200 });
          },
          interceptors: {
            request: {
              use: vi.fn(),
              eject: vi.fn(),
            },
            response: {
              use: vi.fn(),
              eject: vi.fn(),
            },
          },
        };
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

But would like to use something like

```
    (axios.get as MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockImplementationOnce(
      () => promise
    );
```

maybe someone mocked `axios.create` using `vitest` and could share configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, for instance, you're using `axios.create()` in your codebase to generate an `AxiosInstance`, you can mock this functionality as follows in your Vitest test file:

```js
const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({
  get: vi.fn(),
  post: vi.fn(),
}));

vi.mock('axios', async(importActual) => {
  const actual = await importActual<typeof import ('axios')>();

  const mockAxios = {
    default: {
      ...actual.default,
      create: vi.fn(() => ({
        ...actual.default.create(),
        get: mocks.get,
        post: mocks.post,
      })),
    },
  };

  return mockAxios;
});
```

Initially, we set up the `mocks` object that includes the `get` and `post` functions we want to mock. Using `vi.hoisted()`, we ensure these mocked functions are hoisted (i.e., moved to the top of the scope), allowing us to reference them within our `vi.mock()` function.

Then, we mock the entire `axios` module using `vi.mock()`. In order to maintain the existing functionality that we don't intend to mock, we employ `importActual` to import the real `axios` module. We then specify the parts we wish to mock, namely the `create` function and the `get`/`post` functions.

With these mocks in place, we can now spy on our mocked `get` and `post` methods. Here's an example of how to do it:

```js
it('should call axios.get', async() => {
  mocks.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: {},
  });
  await api.getFromAPI();
  expect(mocks.get).toHaveBeenCalled(); // should return true
});
```

In the test case, we mock a resolved value for our `get` method and call the function we want to test (`api.getFromAPI()` in this case). We then check whether our mocked `get` function has been called using `expect().toHaveBeenCalled()`.

This setup provides a controlled environment to test the interactions with the axios library in our code.

Comment: Please do not post [the same answer to more than one question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608028/471272). Also, do not post ChatGPT answers, because they are plagiarism violating the Code of Conduct and officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 5):

So sorted it out, maybe it will help someone.

```
vi.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      post: vi.fn(),
      get: vi.fn(),
      delete: vi.fn(),
      put: vi.fn(),
      create: vi.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      interceptors: {
        request: {
          use: vi.fn(),
          eject: vi.fn(),
        },
        response: {
          use: vi.fn(),
          eject: vi.fn(),
        },
      },
    },
  };
});
```

so basically we mock `axios.create` method to return itself and we can write mocking like this

```
    (axios.post as MockedFunction<typeof axios.post>).mockResolvedValue(
      () => Promise.resolve({ status: 200 })
    );
```