# I'm writing a vitest to call an API and store it in projects with Pinia. I expect an array length of 3, but the array is empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I'm currently working on a Vue.js application using Pinia as a state management library and Vitest for testing. I have an action in one of my Pinia stores that makes an API call to fetch project data and then updates the store's state. However, when I attempt to write a Vitest unit test to mock this API call and then check the state of the store, the store's state doesn't seem to update as expected.

Here is my Pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from '@/utils/axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

export const useProjectStore = defineStore('project', {
    state: () => ({
        projects: []
    }),
    actions: {
        async getAllProjects() {
            this.loading = true;

            try {
                await axios.get('projects', {
                    timeout: 15000
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.projects = response.data;
                }).catch((err) => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
            } catch (error) {
                this.loading = false;
                console.error(error);
            }

            this.loading = false;
        },
    persist: true,
});
```

And here is my Vitest unit test:

```
import { describe, test, expect, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { useProjectStore } from '@/stores/project'
import axios from 'axios'

describe('Projects', () => {
    let store = null
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      setActivePinia(createPinia())
      store = useProjectStore()
    })

    test('that projects is empty at the beginning', () => {
        expect(store.projects).toEqual([])
    })

    test('that the projects is filled with 3 projects', async () => {
      await store.getAllProjects()
      
      expect(store.projects).toHaveLength(3)
    })
})
```

When I run this test, it fails with the message:

> Expected: 3, Received: 0

This indicates that the projects array in the Pinia store is not being updated with the mocked data. I am quite puzzled as to why this is happening, as it seems that I'm properly mocking the API call and updating the state accordingly. Does anyone know why my Pinia state isn't updating as expected in this Vitest unit test? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're supposed to mock network calls in unit tests. This is not done here. it's safe to assume that it results in an error, although you didn't specify if there's error output

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any doc or acticle that I can look at?

Comment: Check the existing questions with relevant keywords, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101502/how-to-mock-axios-with-jest , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072066/mocking-axios-create-using-vitest , etc. Be aware of possible incompatibilities of Vitest in terms of module mocking